# facebook, share only title and content on facebook wall

Tags: html, facebook

I am using this piece of code to share the news on facebook wall:

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="
    window.open(
    'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
    'facebook-share-dialog', 
    'width=626,height=436'); 
     return false;">
     Shpërdaje me shoket
</a>
```

The thing is that all the title, date and some other words i have above the contet are being shared on facebook, How can I make sharing only title and content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sharer respects the [OpenGraph tags](http://ogp.me/). You can define a custom content inside such tags as well as images, author, etc